# How to perform a HTTP redirection using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, redirect, cgi

I am calling my python script after a HTML form is submitted by the user . My python script is present in usr/lib/cgi-bin . I want to redirect to another page depending on the inputs provided by the user , basically I am creating a login script where if the user inputs are valid then the user will be redirected to the loggedin.html page else to error.html page

**signin.py** (i am trying to execute this code)

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7

import cgi, cgitb 

# import pymongo module for connecting to mongodb database

import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# creating a mongo client to the running mongod instance
client = MongoClient()

# selecting the database mydb 
db_mydb = client.mydb

# selecting the collection user
collection_user = db_mydb.user

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Signin</title>"
print "</head>"

# Get data from fields
email = form.getvalue('login-username')
password  = form.getvalue('login-password')

#checking whether user inputs are correct or not
 existence_query=collection_user.find_one({"_id":email,"password":password})

print "<body>"

if(existence_query):
    print "person exists"
    print "Status: 301 Moved\r\n\r\n"
    print "Location : http://localhost/mongo/loggedin.html\r\n\r\n"

else:
    print "person does't exists"
    #redirecting to error.html page
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

Output that I am getting after this script is called from my html form (when user inputs are valid i.e user is a valid):

***person exists Location:http:localhost/mongo/loggedin.html***

I am new to cgi using python so any help would be great to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Python docs on the `cgi` module

> The output of a CGI script should consist of two sections, separated by a blank line. The first section contains a number of headers, telling the client what kind of data is following.

You have to send headers `before` any other data you want to send. To accomplish your goal, just put all the header sending logic before the HTML-sending one.

**But** you'd better move all the form-checking code to another file so it doesn't print anything, just sends redirects and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
 # Import modules for CGI handling 

    import cgi, cgitb 

    # import pymongo module for connecting to mongodb database
    import pymongo
    from pymongo import MongoClient

    # Create instance of FieldStorage 
    form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

    # creating a mongo client to the running mongod instance
    # The code will connect on the default host and port i.e 'localhost' and '27017'
    client = MongoClient()

    # selecting the database mydb 
    db_mydb = client.mydb

    # selecting the collection user
    collection_user = db_mydb.user

    #print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"

    # Get data from fields
    email = form.getvalue('login-username')
    password  =     form.getvalue('login-password')

    #checking whether user inputs are correct or not
    existence_query = collection_user.find_one({"_id":email,"password":password})


    if(existence_query):
        print "Location:http://localhost/mongo/index.html\r\n"
        print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
    else:
        print "Location:http://localhost/mongo/index.html\r\n"
        print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
```

Headers need to be initialized in the starting before any other data being sent to the browser.In the question print statements like print "`<html>`"were written before location header and so the desired result wasn't achieved.